# Getting non-common attributes from AD B2C users with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to retrieve the following attributes: "createdDateTime, extension_xxxxxx_yyyyy, identities" from AD B2C users. With Graph Explorer, I could do this with:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=createdDateTime extension_xxxxxx_yyyyy, identities`

Then, I tried the snippet generated by Graph Explorer for PowerShell

`Get-MgUser -Property “createdDateTime,+ extension_xxxxxx_yyyyy,identities”`

I got the following error:

> Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Syntax error: character '+' is
> not valid at position 17 in 'createdDateTime, +exten ……

I removed the “+” and retried, it had no error, but all the returned fields were blank.
I am using Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK 1.18

Comment: Parameter [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-property) takes a string **array**, so try with `-Property 'createdDateTime', 'extension_xxxxxx_yyyyy', 'identities'`

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use the beta version of the API

```
 Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
```

- CreatedDateTime can be got directly
- Identities can be got directly but it is an array
- extension_xxxxxx_yyyyy is the trickiest, it is packed inside the AdditionalProperties